# Enchanced For Loop

Tags: java, for-loop, foreach

I am trying to write a simple program that will calculate how many students have passed and how many failed an exam.
I am just trying to get the hang of the "enhanced For Loop", but I get the following error in TextPad: (it works fine with an ordinary For loop thought)

```
error: possible loss of precision
            if(marks[element]>40.0){
                     ^
  required: int
  found:    double
```

My program code is:

```
public class Lab9Tut12{
public static void main (String[]args){
    int passed = 0;
    int failed = 0;
    double [] marks = new double[20];
    for(int i=0;i<20;i++){
        marks[i] = Math.random()*100;
        System.out.printf("%.2f", marks[i]);
        System.out.println();
    }

    for(double element:marks){
        if(marks[element]>40.0){
            passed++;
        }
        else{
            failed++;
       }
    }
    System.out.println("Passed: " + passed + " failed: " + failed);
}
```

}

Comment: What do you think `double element` in the enhanced for loop is?

Comment: What you are trying to do at that line is read what is at index `element` in array `marks[]`... But `element` is a `double`, whose maximum integral value is greater than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. Hence the "loss of precision" error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

just write

```
if(element>40.0){
```

that should do the trick.

The enhanced for loop gives you the elements of the list/array and not the index.

Answer (score 2):

In the statement `for(double element:marks){`, `element` **is** a specific element in `marks[]`; it is **not** the array index.

Therefore, use `if (element > 40.0){` instead.

(As an aside, although it's cute to see 40.0 it is unnecessary as the `int` 40 will be converted implicitly to a floating point type prior to the comparison. You can confidently use 40 instead. It's largely down to personal preference though.)

Answer (score 1):

You are using a double value as index in

```
if(marks[element]>40.0)
```

Therefore you do not use your for each loop.

You need to go like this:

```
 if(element>40.0)
```

Comment: I see, I didn't know that the enhanced for loop gives me the value in the index and not the index itself.
Cheers !

Answer (score 1):

**Enhanced for loop**: You can iterate every element of array ( Limitation: **no index control**)

```
for(double e:marks)
```

here 'e' is a element of array, you can directly use it. So use

```
if(element>40.0)
```